# When $(X_n)$ is bounded, $X_n \overset{P}{\longrightarrow} 0$ implies $X_n \overset{L^1}{\longrightarrow} 0$, right? (Proof check)

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, probability-limit-theorems

*Claim:* Let $(X_n)$ be a bounded sequence of random variables, i.e. $|X_n| \leq M$ for some $M > 0$. In this case, $X_n \overset{P}{\longrightarrow} 0$ implies $X_n \overset{L^1}{\longrightarrow} 0$. (Or at least it seems that way; see my proof below.)

I've never seen this fact mentioned anywhere (even when actively googling around), which makes me mistrust it. I'd be grateful if someone would check my proof.

*Proof:*

Fix $\delta > 0$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
E|X_n| &= \int_{\{|X_n| \leq \delta \}} \underbrace{|X(\omega)|}_{\leq \delta} P(d\omega) + \int_{\{|X_n| > \delta \}} \underbrace{|X(\omega)|}_{\leq M} P(d\omega) \\
&\leq \delta \cdot \underbrace{P(|X_n| \leq \delta)}_{\to 1} + M \cdot \underbrace{ P(|X_n| > \delta) }_{\to 0} \to \delta \quad \text{as $n \to \infty$.}
\end{aligned}
$$
so
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} E|X_n| \leq \delta.
$$
Allowing $\delta \downarrow 0$ then yields $\lim_{n \to \infty} E|X_n| = 0. \quad \square$

Comment: Looks good to me. Alternatively convergence in $L^1$ is equivalent to convergence in probability plus uniform integrability. A bounded class of random variables is uniformly integrable.